# Error when creating several YouTube playlists through YouTube V3 API?

Tags: .net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have recently resurrected software from last year used to create and populate up to 50 YouTube playlists in a short time. Whilst testing this year I have run into an error where I can no longer create playlists after the 10th in the list. The specific error is below:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError    The user has created too many
>   playlists recently.    Please try the request again later. [403]

I have so far been unsuccessful in finding a solution, or information at all on this issue besides one similar question.

Does anyone have knowledge of this error, such as how long until the generation of playlists can be continued? or perhaps knowledge of a workaround?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting a delay in between requests? Try slowing down.

Comment: So far I have tried setting an interval between creation to 30 seconds to no success. Sadly it seems to lock for 24 hours so I can't test again until tomorrow. I shall try a 5 minute interval and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Tried an interval of 1 per hour and it's the same thing. I can confirm it's 10 per 24h hours and so the reset is 24 hours after having the error... that's pretty bad, need a YouTube API team response here.

Comment: I have finally received a response on the issue I created on googles IssueTracker. They have stated this is intended behavior and so it will not be changed.

Comment: 10 playlists per day is an "intended behavior"... Same reply on the IssueTracker I have opened. Not acceptable at all :/

Comment: related? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79222309

Answer (score 0):

It’s a “[Status: Won't fix (Intended behavior)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79222309)” of Google.

- Manually or programmatically, in 2023-06, I get limited to **25** lists, without any UI warning in the browser… I’ve first come across your post while **manually** rearranging a “To sort” bucket list. So it’s not even an API problem. And same thing from within their iOS app. And I’m a paying subscriber.
- From what I see in 2023-06, the enforced limit is lifted after **6 hours**, not 24. So you might add a timer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34631273)

Comment: @SamPlusPlus — Rephrased the answer. Is it better?